# Can't access NodeJS instance through NGINX

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I want to deploy a server running on NodeJS to my cloud server.

The server:

OS: CentOS 6.5

External IP: 123.125.130.102

NodeJS code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("http://%s:%s", host, port)

});
```

I am running an instance on this server.

NGINX config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 123.125.130.102;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;

        }
}
```

But I can't seem to access my node application on http://123.125.130.102:80.

I'm new to NodeJS and I don't what is wrong.

Comment: Doesn't `app.listen(8081,` mean the server [is on port 8081](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)?

Comment: My nginx config listen 80,and I think when I access  http://123.125.130.102:80, it will pass to http//:localhost:8081,but it doesn't work.

Comment: try to use curl http://localhost:8081 to see if your node app is running

Comment: Which nginx config are you editing?

Comment: @JumarPolanco yes,I have try it and it is running.

Comment: @DaurenAkilbekov etc/nginx/config.d/default.conf

Comment: Could you try to change this server_name 123.125.130.102 to server_name localhost. And check if localhost works.

Comment: @DaurenAkilbekov thx,I have try it and find it work.Is means that my External IP did not work?But I can ping 123.125.130.102 on my local machine.

Comment: Thanks to everyone,I change my port to 90 and it work!!! Maybe the port of 80 had been used~